# What are the language codes standards for internationalization purposes?

Tags: localization, internationalization

The [ISO Codes for the Representation of Names of Languages](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) although used for [websites](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp) is actually insufficient for software internationalization purposes, since it doesn't distinguish between variants of the same language, such as Portuguese of Portugal and Brazilian Portuguese.

Some [programming languages](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/locale.doc.html) and [operative systems](http://www.debian.org/international/l10n/po/) solve this problem by adding a suffix to specify the variants (pt_PT and pt_BR respectively).

But are there any standardization efforts to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some languages as you may know also support Locale variants, for example Norwegian Nynorsk or Norwegian Bokmal (as no_NO_NY and no_NO respectively).

Windows OS supports the concept of [LCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h88fahh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which contains Language, Sub-Language, sorting options, etc.

Now, onto your question: is there any standardization effort in this area?
To be honest, I have never heard of one. That of course doesn't mean that nobody is working on it. However, I believe that both language identifiers [ISO631](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) and [ISO3166](http://www.iso.org/iso/english_country_names_and_code_elements) exist for reasons not related to information exchange via computers. These codes were needed in foreign trade and I am quite confident that this is the reason they were created.
Please take into account that Locale representation is not standardized, you would see something like en_US, en-US and 1033 for the same thing. If we want to create some sort of standard, we need to think about it first, then as an extension standardize variants. I don't think it will happen very soon if ever...

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia lists a couple of [language codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_code).  The pt_BR format is an [IETF language tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag).

Answer (score 0):

You might like ISO-639-3 better. No one liked -2.